# Regex to get string after a keyword

Tags: php, regex

I need to search for a string in a string and get the part behind that (without spaces).

**Example:**

```
This ABC-Code: 12 3 45
Another ABC-Code: 678 9
```

Now I'm searching for the keyword `ABC-Code:` and I want to get the numbers after that (deleting spaces), so the result would be:

```
12345
6789
```

I tried to solche that with substr(), but the problem is, that previous characters are variable. So I think I have to use a RegEx, like this:

```
preg_match("#ABC-Code:(.*?)\n#", $line, $match);
trim($match); // + remove spaces in the middle of the result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function.

```
$str = <<<EOT
This ABC-Code: 12 3 45
Another ABC-Code: 678 9
EOT;
echo preg_replace_callback('~.*\bABC-Code:(.*)~', function ($m)
        { 
            return str_replace(' ', '', $m[1]);
        }, $str);
```

**Output:**

```
12345
6789
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
preg_match('#ABC-Code: *([ \d]+)\b#', $line, $match);
```

And then use:

```
$num = str_replace(' ', '', $match[1]);
// 12345
```

for you numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this with substr:

```
$string = 'This ABC-Code: 12 3 45';
$search = 'ABC-Code:';
$result = str_replace(' ', '', substr($string, strpos($string, $search) + strlen($search)));
```

But the regex in other answers is certainly prettier :)